# *.tgz not extracting properly

Tags: tar

I've just received some files *.tgz... I've tried tar -xvzf file.tgz... However I'm getting error "Attempt to write to an empty file"... Am I missing something... The folder directory system has been made but all the directories are empty...

Thanks.

Comment: Any hint about the environment? Could you please post detail with the output of " tar --version"?

Answer (score 1):

I was using BSD tar... and I needed to use GNU tar.... On Mac OSX use "gnutar -xvzf"